# Why won't list float to the beginning of div?

Tags: html, css, position, css-float

My brain isn't working. Please, let yours work for mine for 1 minute.

The code is very simple.

```
<ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="">Plumbing</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Flooring</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Kitchen</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Bathroom</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Re-decoration</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Structural works</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Electrical</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Re-planning</a></li>
</ul>
```

And some CSS styling:

```
#nav {margin:auto;width:960px;height:29px;background: url(../images/navbg_03.gif);box-shadow: 0px 10px  30px #cccccc;}
#nav li {position:relative;display:block;float:left;}
```

So simple, but it boggles my mind as to why when I float it, it leaves a gap before the beginning of the element.

Comment: Not seeing what you're seeing, can you elaborate on this: http://jsfiddle.net/gQMvT

Comment: @NickVeys turn off normalize css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ul`s usually have padding or margin in the user agent styles, just add

```
#nav{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand. The margin doesn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: padding-left:0px; would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

A crutch I always fall back on is throwing borders on everything.  Doing this shows there is some padding shoving things over: http://jsfiddle.net/gQMvT/5

```
* { border: 1px solid black; }
```

Answer (score 0):

hey the margin should be made 0px
as well as the padding 
the css code should look like this

```
#nav {margin:0px;width:960px;height:29px;background: url(../images/navbg_03.gif);box-shadow: 0px 10px  30px #cccccc;}
#nav li {position:relative;display:block;float:left;}
```